# Python : How to serve files

Tags: python, file, download

Im currently doing a side project for myself, and i would like to create a webpage, with basically a button that'll download a file ( more specifically an apple wallet file, but this isn't important ) .
The front end side is okay, but i'm having trouble with the back end side. I'm having trouble to render a downloadable file.

Here's what i wrote

```
@view_config(name='pkpass', request_method='POST')
def post_mobile(request):
   #i've shortened this for readability
   b64 = 'JIDEWJIODEW'
   b64decoded = base64.b64decode(b64)
   try :
      res = Response(body=b64decoded, content_type = 'application/octet-stream')
      res.content_disposition = 'attachment; filename="test.pkpass"'
   except Exception as e :
      print(e)

   return res
```

But there's few thing that i don't get. How will the browser know this file have to be downloaded ? i mean, how the auto-download will start ? Also, nothing happen when i click my link. I've made sure that the backend was correctly called, but i'm not sure about the return value

PS : adding a SC [image]
Edit 2 : HTML Screen shot

[image]

Comment: what web framework are you using as backend?

Comment: the download is triggered when the browser comes across a content-type it cannot render inline, which should be the case with `application/vnd.apple.pkpass`

Comment: I believe the `Content-Disposition` header is also relevant, although I can't tell whether that's really what this question is asking about.

Comment: @hansaplast im using turbogears

Comment: @JorelAmthor are you sure? there's no `view_config` in the turbogears docs: [search for view_config on turbogears doc](http://turbogears.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search.html?q=view_config&check_keywords=yes&area=default)

Comment: @hansaplast i meant to say pyramid ofc :D sorry i got confused